# clearTimeout behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, rollover, onmouseout

I'm working on a template file and have 3 list items that when you rollover highlighted text for each a div which loads hidden made visible. On mouse out a delay is set before the div becomes hidden again. The clearTimeout is for if the user is going between the listed items so the newly selected div loads and the old one is hidden once more. I have the script working sort of which is why I need help. When you roll over the items from the bottom item up the clearTimeout works just like I want it to, but if you go from the first item down it doesn't clear the timeouts at all.

```
<script>function myClear1()
{
    clearTimeout(myFunction1, myFunction2, myFunction3);
    }
function myFunction1()
{
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('relatedproduct1').style.display = 'none';},500);
}
function myFunction2()
{
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('relatedproduct2').style.display = 'none';},500);
}
function myFunction3()
{
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('relatedproduct3').style.display = 'none';},500);
}
</script>
```

Those are the scripts and below I'll add in the code from where it is being used on the page.

```
<form class="relatedcheckboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="relatedcheckboxes">
<div style="display:inline;cursor:pointer; color:#00F; background-color:#FFF;"onmouseover="document.getElementById('relatedproduct1').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('selectedProductsGroup').style.display ='none'; myClear1()"onmouseout="myFunction1()">Product Number:</div> Product Name - Sale Price
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product Name" value="" class="relatedcheckboxes">
<div style="display:inline; cursor:pointer; color:#00F; background-color:#FFF;"onmouseover="document.getElementById('relatedproduct2').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('selectedProductsGroup').style.display ='none';myClear1()"onmouseout="myFunction2()">Product Number</div>: Product Name - Sale Price
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Product Name" value="" class="relatedcheckboxes">
<div style="display:inline; cursor:pointer; color:#00F; background-color:#FFF;"onmouseover="document.getElementById('relatedproduct3').style.display = 'block';  myClear1()"onmouseout="myFunction3()">Product Number</div>: Product Name - Sale Price
</form>
```

Comment: Reading some documentation, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout , would have prevented some/all of your trouble

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the return value of `setTimeout` to `clearInterval`, not your functions. For example:

```
var timer = setTimeout(func, 1000);
clearTimeout(timer);
```

---

Adapting your code with minimal changes would be something like this:

```
var timer1;
function myClear1(){
    clearTimeout(timer1);
}
function myFunction1() {
    return setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('relatedproduct1').style.display = 'none';
    },500);
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="myClear1()" onmouseout="timer1=myFunction1()">...</div>...
```

Comment: This looks like you're clearing the timeout at the same time you're doing the time delay. I have very little experience with javascript so @bfavaretto I'll need some more details to follow what you're trying to tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am, that was just an basic example. I'll add an example based on your code.

Comment: Okay I tried this and it is behaving in a similar way except when I roll from one item to the next now It keeps the previous on visible even after the last one has finished its timeout. Plus it seems like the clear only works from bottom up like before.

Comment: `clearTimeout` just clears the timer. If you are expecting to do something else, it won't.

Comment: but the timer is what is keeping the previous item visible after you mouseout so if I mouseover a new item before the timer is over it should clear the timer which would then return the div to hidden.

Comment: Your timers hide the divs after 500ms. If you cancel any of them, the divs should stay they way they are (in other words, not be hidden after 500ms). Suggestion: rework your code to remove all the inline js and css, then update your question with an example to reproduce the problem (or ask a new question).